# Add radio button in a callback with GtkAda

Tags: ada, gnat, gtkada

here i start with GtkAda but i met a problem that i don't understand. I give you a summary of the code.

file.ads

```
With Gtk.Window;        Use Gtk.Window;
With Gtk.Table;         Use Gtk.Table;
With Gtk.Widget;        use Gtk.Widget;
With Gtk.Alignment;     Use Gtk.Alignment;

Package File is

   Type Align is array ( Positive range <> ) of Gtk_Alignment;

   Type T_Test_Record is tagged record

      Conteneur : Gtk_Table;
      Win : Gtk_Window;
      Button1 : Gtk_Button;
      Button2 : Gtk_Button;

   end record;

   Type T_Test is access all T_Test_Record;

   Align_Elements : Align(1..2);

   Procedure Initialize_Window ( Window : out T_Test_Record ) ;

   --   Initialize the Window of Gtk_Window type.

   Procedure Initialize_Table ( Table : out T_Test_Record );

   --   Initialze the Table of Gtk_Table type.

   Procedure Initialize_Buttons ( Button : T_Test );

   --   Initialize the Button1 and button2 of Gtk_Button type.

   Procedure Show_Window ( Window : out T_Test_Record );

   --    Display the Window with the method Gtk.Widgdet.Show_All

Private

   Procedure Exit_Window (Window : access Gtk_Widget_Record'Class);

   --   Callback to Close the Window.

end file;
```

File.adb

```
With Gtk.Main; Use Gtk.Main;

Package body File is

   Procedure Initialize_Window ( Window : out T_Test_Record ) is
   begin

      Gtk_New (Window.Win);

      Window.Win.Set_Default_Size (Width  => 600,
                                   Height => 400);

      P.Connect (Window.Win,
                 Name   => Signal_Destroy,
                 Marsh  => P.To_Marshaller (Exit_Window'Access),
                 After  => False);

   end Initialize_Window;

   Procedure Initialize_Buttons ( Button : T_Test ) is
   Begin

      Gtk_New (Button.Button1,Label => "Bouton1");

      Gtk_New (Button.Button2,Label => "Bouton2");

      For i in Align_Elements'range loop

         Case i is

            When 1 => Gtk_New (Align_Elements(i),
                               Xalign => 0.0,
                               Yalign => 0.0,
                               Xscale => 0.0,
                               Yscale => 0.0);

               Align_Elements(i).Add (Button.Button1);

            When 2 => Gtk_new (Align_Elements(i),
                               Xalign => 0.5,
                               Yalign => 0.0,
                               Xscale => 0.0,
                               Yscale => 0.0);

               Align_Elements(i).Add (Button.Button2);

         end case;
      end loop;

      Test2.P.Connect (Widget => Button.Button1,
                       Name   => Signal_Clicked,
                       Marsh  => P.To_Marshaller
(Callback_Bouton1'Access),
                       After  => False);

   end Initialize_Buttons;

   Procedure Initialize_Table ( Table : out T_Test_Record ) is

      Window : T_Test;
   begin
      Window := New T_Test_Record;

      Initialize_Window (Window => Table);
      Initialize_Buttons (Button => Window);

      Gtk_New (Table.Conteneur,
               Rows        => 0,
               Columns     => 0,
               Homogeneous => False);

      For i in Align_Elements'range loop

         Table.Conteneur.Add (Align_Elements(i));

      end loop;
       Table.Win.Add (Table.Conteneur);

   end Initialize_Table;

   Procedure Show_Window (Window : out T_Test_Record ) is
   begin

      Initialize_Table (Table => Window);

      Window.Win.Show_All;
   end Show_Window;

   Procedure Exit_Window ( Window : access Gtk_Widget_Record'Class)
is
   begin

      Main_Quit;
   end Exit_Window;
end File;
```

file2.ads

```
With file;              Use file;
With Gtk.Radio_Button;  Use Gtk.Radio_Button;
With Gtk.Handlers;

Package file2 is

   Package P is new Gtk.Handlers.Callback (Gtk_Widget_Record);

   Use P;

   Type Continent is (Europa, America, Africa, Asia);

   Type Payment_Mode ( Choose : Continent := America ) is record

      bank_Transfer : Gtk_Radio_Button;

      Case Choose is

         When Europa | America | Asia =>

            By_Check : Gtk_Radio_Button;
            By_Card : Gtk_Radio_Button;

         When Africa => null;

      end case;
   end record;

   Type Test_Record Is new T_Test_Record with record

      Method : Payment_Mode;
      Amount : Integer;

   end record;

   Type Test is access all Test_Record'class;

   Procedure Saisir_Montant ( Saisie : out Test_Record );

   Procedure Choose_Payment_Mode ( Mode : Test );

   Procedure Callback_Bouton1 (Emet : access Gtk_Widget_Record'Class);

end file2;
```

File2.adb

```
With Ada.Integer_Text_IO;  Use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

Package body file2 is

   Procedure Saisir_Montant (Saisie : out Test_Record ) is
   begin

      Put_Line ("Entry Amount");

      Get (Saisie.Amount); Skip_Line;

   end Saisir_Montant;

   Procedure Choose_Payment_Mode (Mode : Test ) is

      Local_Variable : Test_Record;
   begin
      Saisir_Montant (Local_Variable);

      Put_Line ("What's your payment mode ?");

      Gtk_New (Mode.Method.bank_transfer,
               Group => null,
               Label => "Wire");


            Gtk_New (Mode.Method.By_Check,
                     Group => null,
                     Label => "Check");

            Gtk_New (Mode.Method.By_Card,
                     Group => null,
                     Label => "Card");

   end Choose_Payment_Mode;

   Procedure Callback_Bouton1 (Emet : access Gtk_Widget_Record'Class) is

      Local_Variable : Test;
   begin
      Local_Variable := New Test_Record;

      Choose_Payment_Mode (Mode => Local_Variable);
      Initialize_Table (Table => Local_Variable.all);

      Local_Variable.Conteneur.Add (Local_Variable.Method.bank_transfer);
      Local_Variable.Conteneur.Add (Local_Variable.Method.By_Check);
      Local_Variable.Conteneur.Add (Local_Variable.Method.By_Card);

      Local_Variable.Conteneur.Show_All;

   end Callback_Bouton1;
end File2;
```

Main_Program.Adb

```
With file;                 Use file;

Procedure Main_Program is

   Test : T_Test_Record;
begin
   Init;

   Show_Window (Window => Test);

   Main;
end Main_Program;
```

the program compile and execute well but don't show me my Gtk_Radio_Button (in package File2.Choose_Payment_Mode) called when click on button1. the callback works very well but my Gtk_Radio_Button don't Show. yet i don't see any error.